# Using JQuery in Angular 6: how to dynamically generate id for a HTML element and select it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using Angular 6 and I am working with a JQuery table plugin (DataTable).

in my HTML I put

```
<table [id]="'t1'" class="display">
```

and in the typescript file, I put

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#t1').DataTable({
          data: data, //data
          columns: columns //column definition
        });
      });
```

It works great.
But now I have multiple tables, I want to give  a dynamic id.
here tablename is a local variable. I put:

```
 <table [id]="tablename" class="display">
```

And in typescript file:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#'+this.tablename).DataTable({
                  data: data, //data
                  columns: columns //column definition
                });
              });
```

Now the table does not show up at all.

I 've worked with Angular for a while, I believe the syntax is correct, I saw no complain in console but I can not figure out why it does not work.

I truly appreciate any help.

Comment: try add  <table [attr.id]="tablename" class="display">

Comment: Alreardy tried. not working.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use jquery plugin? Just think a little more insight into the why might help from getting the down votes.

Comment: I hope those downvoted the question give me a little heads up. I 've researched for some time a good table option in the Angular ecosystem. Aside from searching, paging, sorting, I especially need editing function. I have not find a good one.  I also welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting code "in TypeScript" file?

Comment: inside ngOnInit()

Comment: That's your problem. Move the code to `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Still not working. But thank you for the help.

Comment: i'm not sure about this, but try to rename the property binding [id] to something else about table plugin that could be very helpful for you case is primeng
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/ i'm using it in big project and it works good

Comment: Thank you guys for the discussion. Obviously inside that JQuery call 'this' is pointing at something else. Common mistake that already bite me several times.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendaion. I will check it out.

Comment: Typing "npm install jquery --save" will get you kicked of my projects instantly. No questions asked, no chances given. You will not be coming back.

Comment: There's something wrong in using JQuery inside Angular. Maybe you need to re-start with a good tutorial. It's everythign wrong

Answer (score 1):

I have ported the jQuery data table to Angular and have a stack blitz of it here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdn6nq

The css is not included but it will look ok if you have the jquery datatable css.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer after some try and test:

**Mistake**: inside that JQuery call 'this' is pointing at something else other than the angular component. So this.tablename is **undefined**. such a common mistake in JavaScript.

**Solution**:  standard: outside JQuery,

```
let self =this
```

And call with self.tablename.

Comment: If you use an arrow function instead of a normal function this is always the current object, not the object it is called from. $(document).ready(() => { // this is still your component and not jQuery });